# Moment generating function of two non-independent Brownian increments

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I am writing to ask if it is possible to get closed-form solution to the expression to the following expression:
$\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma^2(W_t-W_u)(W_s-W_u)}]$ where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion, $\sigma$ a constant, and assume $u \leq s \leq t$ .

Note that the increments above are not independent. Also for the case when $s=t$, we see that the expression is simply the moment generating function of a chi-squared distribution. However, for $s\neq t$, it is not immediately clear to me how to deal with this expression or simplify it further. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $(W_t-W_u)(W_s-W_u)=XY+Y^2$ with $X=W_t-W_s$ and $Y=W_s-W_u$.
- Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $E[\mathrm e^{a(XY+Y^2)}\mid Y]=u(aY)\mathrm e^{aY^2}$ where $u(x)=E[\mathrm e^{xX}]$.
- Hence $E[\mathrm e^{a(XY+Y^2)}]=E[u(aY)\mathrm e^{aY^2}]$.
- Now, $u(x)=$ $______$ and the distribution of $Y$ is $______$ hence $E[\mathrm e^{a(XY+Y^2)}]=$ $________$.